# Is this an appropriate way to add a single-pole switch (without a gang box) to a circuit with an existing single-pole switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have a fun electrical challenge in my basement. I currently have power coming off of the breaker, to a single light fixture, and then on to a single-pole switch (Figure 1). I would like to add a new single-pole switch (on the other side of the room from the existing switch) on this existing circuit to just control the new light fixture. I still want the existing switch to only control the existing light fixture.

I know that I could install a pull-chain light fixture in parallel to the existing fixture, which would preclude the need for a new switch. This isn't a bad idea, but my wife would prefer a switch on the wall and wants the new light fixture to match the existing light fixture in the basement. I could also put the new switch in a gang box with the existing switch and just run wire all the way over to the new light, but we would like the new switch to be quite close to the new fixture on the other side of the room. There are no other circuits that I can easily tie into in this basement, and running a new circuit from the breaker is overkill (I think) for just one light fixture.

I took my best guess (Figure 2) as to what the desired circuit should look like. Does figure 2 look like an appropriate and safe way to wire this particular set up? Thanks for all your help.
[image: Existing Circuit]
[image: Desired Circuit]

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it possible, but you seem to have it figured out already and even have a nifty wiring diagram to follow to accomplish it.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you ArchonOSX. I think figure 2 is reasonable, but I wasn't sure as I couldn't find a comparable wiring diagram, and I'm a DIYer--not a professional. I'll hook it up and report back.